# What's the difference between a call to a base class method and a child class method in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript

I'm working on rewriting some old JS code to CoffeeScript and, in the process, cleaning it up and converting stuff to a more object-oriented format.

I have a [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) view model for a user edit form. I'm also using jQuery and [knockout.validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) for client-side validation. I've converted it to a CoffeesScript class and it works great. Now I'm converting some other code (other view models) and I want to create a base class for my view models that includes some of the code that's common to all these view models. But I'm finding that methods called on the base class are not working, while methods called on the subclass are.

Here's an example - a User view model:

This is the original code:

```
class User
    constructor: (values)->
        // set up the view model properties as knockout observables

        // set up the validation rules

    bindKnockout: (@selector)->
        // create a validated observable viewmodel & bind it to the
        // DOM elements
        ko.applyBindings(ko.validatedObservable(@), $(@selector)[0])
```

This works great. After the form is created, the user model is instantiated, and the `bindKnockout` method is called.

But most or all of my view models will have a `bindKnockout` method that is identical, so I thought I'd inherit that from a base class:

```
class ViewModel
    bindKnockout: (@selector)->
        // create a validated observable viewmodel & bind it to the
        // DOM elements
        ko.applyBindings(ko.validatedObservable(@), $(@selector)[0])

class User extends ViewModel
    constructor: (values)->
        // set up the view model properties as knockout observables

        // set up the validation rules
```

When I do this, however, I get an error in my browser's console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "disable: function (){return !isValid() }"
Message: isValid is not defined
```

This error is being thrown by Knockout and indicates that the `isValid` observable is not present on my view model. The `isValid` observable is added to the view model by the knockout.validation plugin and returns a boolean value indicating whether the model passed validation or not. It is present and working fine in the first example (with no base class), but as soon as I move it to the base class it fails.

I've examined the Javascript generated from my source. Here's the original code from the User model (without the base model):

```
User.prototype.bindKnockout = function(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
    return ko.applyBindings(ko.validatedObservable(this), $(this.selector)[0]);
};
```

And in the second case, with inheritance from the base model:

```
Viewmodel.prototype.bindKnockout = function(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
    return ko.applyBindings(ko.validatedObservable(this), $(this.selector)[0]);
};
```

Given that the code is the same, the problem must lie in the binding of `this`, right? But I've done a `console.log(@)` for both methods and I can't find a difference.

Can anyone explain how inheritance is working (or not working the way I expect) in this case?

Comment: I've made a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8crw6s1t/) to try this out, and I am not running into the error. Maybe you can modify it to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You've covered all the obvious potential problems I can think of, but if I may suggest an alternative to inheritance, javascript makes mixins rather trivial and they are far more decoupled. Classes are themselves values in coffeescript, its not too hard to write a helper function that takes a class as its first argument and a variable number of mixins gathered with the `...` operator and applies them. Maybe not what you're looking for but I've just been burned by inheritance too many times.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle @RoyJ - I'll spend some time looking at it this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

As mentioned above, I'm converting a bunch of old Javascript to CoffeeScript. This requires some reorganization, particularly of dependencies like jQuery & Knockout. As it turns out, I was actually including the Knockout and Knockout.validation libraries twice - once in my HTML script tags and once in the dependencies for my Javascript code (I'm using Browserify to bundle everything). It seems that Knockout or Knockout.validation don't like that...